# BeautifulSoup web scraping all 'li' text to dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape a list list of properties from a real estate web site and pass them into a data table. I am using python 3.

The following code I have works to print the required data. But I need a way to output the data into table. Between each li tag are 3 items, a property number (1 - 50), tenant name and square footage. ideally the output would be structured in a data frame with column headers number, tenant, square footage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("http://properties.kimcorealty.com/properties/0014/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

start = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'units_box_1'})
for litag in start.find_all('li'):
    print(litag.text)

start = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'units_box_2'})
for litag in start.find_all('li'):
    print(litag.text)

start = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'units_box_3'})
for litag in start.find_all('li'):
    print(litag.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, getting all the divs in one go, finding enclosing "a" tags for groups of 3 "li" tags containing one set of data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodedata
from pandas import DataFrame

page = requests.get("http://properties.kimcorealty.com/properties/0014/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = []
# Find all the divs we need in one go.
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id':['units_box_1', 'units_box_2', 'units_box_3']})
for div in divs:
    # find all the enclosing a tags.
    anchors = div.find_all('a')
    for anchor in anchors:
        # Now we have groups of 3 list items (li) tags
        lis = anchor.find_all('li')
        # we clean up the text from the group of 3 li tags and add them as a list to our table list.
        table.append([unicodedata.normalize("NFKD",lis[0].text).strip(), lis[1].text, lis[2].text.strip()])
# We have all the data so we add it to a DataFrame.
headers = ['Number', 'Tenant', 'Square Footage']
df = DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
print (df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Number                          Tenant Square Footage
0       1                  Nordstrom Rack         34,032
1       2               Total Wine & More         29,981
2       3           Thomasville Furniture         10,628
...
47     49                  Jo-Ann Fabrics         45,940
48     50                       Available         32,572
```